# Issue in load Web API data in grid ionic framework

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

i m new in ionic and i want to load my web api data in grid ionic so below is my code.

**grid.html**

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-title>Grid Demo</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
   <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>


 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let product of products">
    <ion-col width-50 >
         <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
    </ion-col>

     </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>


  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
 </ion-content>
```

**grid.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { ProductListProvider } from '../../providers/product/product'


 @Component({
    templateUrl: 'grid.html',
    providers:[ProductListProvider]
 })

 export class  GridHttpPage {
   public response: any;
   public products: any =[];
   public count: any;
   public loader: any;
   public page: number = 0;
   public isLoading: boolean =true;
   public totalItem: number ;


  doRefresh(refresher) {
  console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.page=0;
    this.loadData(true);
    console.log('Async operation has ended');
    refresher.complete();
  }, 2000);
}

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public personListProvider: ProductListProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
this.count = 0;
this.loadData(this.isLoading);
  }

 presentLoading() {
this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  // spinner: 'hide',
  content: "Please wait...",
  // duration: 3000,
  // showBackdrop: true,
  // enableBackdropDismiss: true,
  // dismissOnPageChange: true
   });

  this.loader.onDidDismiss(() => {
  // console.log('Dismissed loading');
 });

 this.loader.present();
 }

 loadData(isLoading) {


if(isLoading==true)
{
  this.presentLoading();
}


this.page ++;
this.personListProvider.load(this.page)
  .then(data => {
    this.response = data;
    this.totalItem =  this.response.listing.total;
    //this.products = this.response.listing.data;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.response.listing.data.length; i++) {


      this.products.push(this.response.listing.data[i]);

    //  console.log(this.response.listing.data[i]);
    }



    if(isLoading==true)
    {
      this.loader.dismiss();
    }

    console.log(this.response.listing);
    console.log(this.products);
    console.log(this.totalItem);

    });
  }
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
console.log('Begin async operation');

setTimeout(() => {
  // for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  //   this.items.push( this.items.length );
  // }
  if(this.products.length <= this.totalItem )
  {
    this.loadData(false);
  }


  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  infiniteScroll.complete();
  }, 500);
 }


}
```

When i run above code i get following type of output Refer screenshots.

[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWlB2.png)

It display single column list i want to display in 2 column so any idea how can i display in two column in gridview ionic?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution

Make change in grid.ts file

```
rows: any;
```

in loadata funtion

```
loadData(isLoading) {


if(isLoading==true)
{
  this.presentLoading();
}


this.page ++;
this.personListProvider.load(this.page)
  .then(data => {
    this.response = data;
    this.totalItem =  this.response.listing.total;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.response.listing.data.length; i++) {


      this.products.push(this.response.listing.data[i]);

     }
   this.rows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.products.length / 2)).keys()); 



    if(isLoading==true)
    {
      this.loader.dismiss();
    }

    console.log(this.response.listing);
    console.log(this.products);
    console.log(this.totalItem);

   });
 }
```

in grid.html change as follows

```
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let i of rows">
   <ion-col  *ngFor="let product of products | slice:(i*2):(i+1)*2" width-50 (click)="openDetailPage(product)">
     <ion-card>
   <ion-avatar item-left>
     <img src="{{product.medium_image}}" />
   </ion-avatar>
   <ion-card-content>
   <ion-card-title>
   <h6>{{product.title}}</h6>
  <p> <b>Price: </b> {{product.price}}</p>
  </ion-card-title>
   </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
  </ion-col>

  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```